# Take a snapshot from a video-react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video, video-reactjs

#### video-react

#### capture-frame

I'm trying to get a snapshot from a ***video-react*** using ***capture-frame*** but when I call the function captureFrame(video) it trhows the next.

> error:Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on
> 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

My code is the following:

```
captureSnapshot = () => {
    const video = this.player_video.video.video;
    video.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    console.log(video);
    
    const buf = captureFrame(video);
    const image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    image.setAttribute('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(new window.Blob([buf])));
    
    
    console.log('captured frame src', image);
    this.setState({ image: image.src });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically was solve the error including the **crossOrigin** in the props of the ***video-react*** player just like this:

```
<Player
   ref={player => { this.player_video = player }}
   crossOrigin={'anonymous'}
/>
```

Comment: putting `crossOrigin={'anonymous'}` did not work for me